# How Do I Stop or Disable Scheduler if I've found a possible PermGen memory leak with Tomcat and Akka?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, memory-leaks, akka

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to disable the Akka Scheduler thread as I might have found a memory leak(?).

I have a Java-Spring application running on Tomcat that registers my Akka ActorSystem with basic configuration - i.e. I haven't provided an application.conf, I'm just going with the standard defaults for everything for the moment. 
The work done by the actors that get spawned is just simple creation of a Spring RestTemplate object that get some JSON from a service and Jackson is then used to create some objects.

On my production servers, which are under fairly large load during retail sales, I've recently noticed my PermGen space slowly creeping up now I've put in the ActorSystem.

So to find the source of the problem I ran the application locally, let my Tomcat container initialise the Spring application - which in turn instantiates an actor system. Simple. All good. Until...

I started looking at VisualVM memory Sampling.

Without even hitting a page - so the app has started up and NOTHING else has taken place, no requests, nada... the sleeping Thread of the scheduler "myActorSystem-scheduler-1" appears to be using memory. Grabbing memory at about 8kb/sec. (possibly per "tick").

I left VisualVM running overnight and came in to find 300MB of PermGen was just GONE.
My production servers have a different configuration than development to some degree, but when the server is sitting idle the ONLY THING that's using memory is this scheduler. If the server isn't interacting with anything and the scheduler isn't even used - AT ALL - it really shouldn't be skimming my memory.

I haven't configured the Akka actor system to do anything that isn't out of the box.

If you debug **akka.dispatch.AbstractNodeQueue** you'll find that this constructor is called on every 'tick'...

```
private volatile Node<T> _tailDoNotCallMeDirectly;

protected AbstractNodeQueue() {
   final Node<T> n = new Node<T>();
   _tailDoNotCallMeDirectly = n;
   set(n);
}
```

Instantiating an object that gets set to a "value" variable reference inside this class:

```
public class AtomicReference<V>  implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1848883965231344442L;

private static final Unsafe unsafe = Unsafe.getUnsafe();
private static final long valueOffset;

static {
  try {
    valueOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset
        (AtomicReference.class.getDeclaredField("value"));
  } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Error(ex); }
}

private volatile V value;

/**
 * Sets to the given value.
 *
 * @param newValue the new value
 */
public final void set(V newValue) {
    value = newValue;
}
```

I've seen Tomcat configurations such as:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

that enable Tomcat to sweep the PermGen space and clean it out if it can. ("can" - this is the garbage collector we're talking about). 
On the production servers I added these lines and my servers are actually using less PermGen on average than normal, now. This is a good thing, however:

- is this really necessary though? If this is a genuine memory leak I'd rather not just "work-around" the problem especially since I've never had PermGen issues before I started using this very basic Akka ActorSystem implementation.
- Will instantiating such a static class on every tick not put something into the PermGen space every time? Am I wrong in thinking this is a memory leak?
- Can I turn off the akka Scheduler if I DON'T NEED to schedule an actor work to trigger in the future?. (I only want to trigger actors on requests as they arrive). I only see config for a scheduler's tick time in the docs. It would be useful to deactivate it, to test this issue. Or am I missing something, that the Scheduler is very important? As it never does anything even with my App getting hit and creating actors. The thread just sleeps and eats my memory.

Any ideas peeps? Many thanks.

Comment: Akka uses the scheduler internally for stuff, like timeout handling when you use ask so I don't think you can just stop it. We use Akka (albeit purely in Scala) in production to run a fairly complex system and we've never had issues with the scheduler and memory. Something else must be at play here.

Comment: Also, those static vars on AtomicReference are not tied to instances of AtomicReference and are therefore only instantiated once. To say that a new static class is created and put onto perm gen is not correct given this example.

Comment: Facing similar issue. Did you find any solution about this?